# How to create a parent-child structure of a database in Excel

Tags: database, excel, structure, parent-child

I need to create a hierachical structure on excel and data looks like this:

```
DivisionCode     DivisionName             DivisionParentCode 
1                General Management        
143              Marketing                1
123              Data Marketing           143
167              Human Ressource          1
189              Finance                  1
156              Accounting               189
1889             Tax collection           189
1677             Data analytics           143
16788            Deep Learning            1677
13455            Quantitative analysis    1677
17890            Qualitative analysis     1677
199005           Algorithm                16788
```

Each line corresponds to a department/service of a company. I have the code of the department (DivisionCode) and the code of it's department parent (DivisionParentCode). I would like to create a structure that would look like this:

```
DivisionCode     DivisionName             DivisionParentCode 
1                General Management        
143              Marketing                1
123              Data Marketing           143
1677             Data analytics           143
16788            Deep Learning            1677
199005           Algorithm                16788
13455            Quantitative analysis    1677
17890            Qualitative analysis     1677
167              Human Ressource          1
189              Finance                  1
156              Accounting               189
1889             Tax collection           189
```

I would like to structure the data by service/department "parenthood". I am wondering if there is a formula in excel that will enable me to structure my data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this data currently in a database that you could submit SQL against to put it in this structure? I think it would be relatively simple with a recursive CTE SQL statement. Doing it in excel may get a little hairy.

Comment: @JNevill yes it is. Any idea how I could write this CTE SQL statement ?

Comment: I've added an answer where I take a shot at the Recursive CTE to achieve this sort. It should be pretty close to working (swapping out your table name) and fixing any fat fingering I may have added.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in SQL is pretty simple with a Recursive CTE (Assuming SQL Server here, but Postgres, Oracle, and most majore RDBMS have a version of Recursive CTE implemented)

The syntax here is a little tough to wrap your head around the first time you encounter these but once you get past the syntax it all makes sense.

A recursive CTE takes three parts:

1. The Recursive Anchor/Seed - This is the starting point for the hierarchy. In your case it's any record that has a Parent that is NULL.
2. The Recursive Term - This is the part where the CTE refers back to itself. It's run over and over again until the join fails. We start a DivisionCode 1, and look up the record that has 1 as a Parent. Then we look up the record that has that record as a parent, and on and on.
3. Finally we SELECT from the cte.

I've added in a PATH which will keep track of which records we've hit as we've moved down through the hierarchy, and a Depth that tracks how deep we've gone. We can use these to achieve your sort in excel. You may want to bring those fields back as well by specifying them in the final SELECT clause since they hold a ton of info about the hierarchy.

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    --Create the recursive anchor/seed
    SELECT 
        DivisionCode,
        DivisionName,
        DivisionParentCode,
        CAST(DivisionCode AS VARCHAR(500)) AS Path,
        1 as Depth
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE DivisionParentCode IS NULL

    --Now the recursive term
    SELECT
        t2.DivisionCode,
        t2.DivisionName,
        t2.DivisionParentCode,
        CAST(t1.path + '>' + t2.DivisionCode AS VARCHAR(500)),
        t1.Depth + 1
    FROM
        recCTE t1
        INNER JOIN yourtable t2
            ON t1.DivisionCode = t2.DivisionParentCode
    WHERE depth < 20 --just in case of cycling
)
SELECT 
    DivisionCode,
    DivisionName,
    DivisionParentCode
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY depth, path;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following [recursive SQL CTE query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx)
In the referred article, you will find the exact below solution.
I hope it helps,

```
;with cte as (
    select
        DivisionCode,
        DivisionName,
        DivisionParentCode,
        CAST(DivisionCode as varchar(100)) as Hierarchy
    from HierarchyTable where DivisionParentCode is null
    union all
    select
        h.DivisionCode,
        h.DivisionName,
        h.DivisionParentCode,
        CAST(cte.Hierarchy + ':' + CAST(h.DivisionCode as varchar(100)) as varchar(100)) as Hierarchy    
    from cte 
    inner join HierarchyTable h
        on cte.DivisionCode = h.DivisionParentCode
)
select *
from cte
order by Hierarchy
```

You can see contents of the hierarchy column and how it is used for sorting the output data as you require

[image]